# iphone embedding images in the executable file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

When releasing to the application store someone wrote in an offhand comment that you need to avoid embedding your images into the executable.

How do you do that?

Comment: Where did you see this and what do they mean? Of course you are able to include images in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen code in various books that suggests encoding images as C byte array constants in the source code, and I can say that that's definitely a bad idea for reasons ranging from inefficient pixel formats to unsalvageable memory. That would qualify as "in the executable file" in a way that bundle resources don't, since bundle resources are packaged alongside the executable rather than within it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get you correctly, but maybe he meant accidentally adding image files to the `Compile Sources` category in your build target? This usually does not happen with images, but i have seen it happening with `js` files.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps they meant that you should only include images in the bundle that are essential.

The bundle is essentially read-only so you cannot remove an image from the device that is in the bundle. Therefore placing lots of example images that you expect a user to remove/not want is not a good idea because when the user deletes the images from inside your app no space on the device will be reclaimed.

Of course it is fine to place images in the bundle just make sure that they are required and are not taking up unnecessary space that the user cannot reclaim.